# if no value, do nothing else

Tags: python, xbmc

here the code

```
import subprocess,os
import xbmcgui
import xbmc
import xbmcaddon
import urllib2
import re
import string

#Initialize value for ref.
menu          = 0
video         = 0
audio         = 0
music_title   = 0
music_title1  = 1

#Initialize ADDON
settings = xbmcaddon.Addon(id='micasaverde.addon')

#Initialize ADDON INFORMATION
ip  =  settings.getSetting( "vera_ip" )
dev  =  settings.getSetting( "vera_dev" )

while (not xbmc.abortRequested):
    win   = (xbmcgui.getCurrentWindowId())

    if xbmc.Player().isPlayingAudio():
        tag = xbmc.Player().getMusicInfoTag()
        music_title = tag.getTitle()
        music_title = music_title.replace(' ', '_')
        if music_title != music_title1:
            urllib2('http://%s:3480/data_request?id=variableset&DeviceNum=%s&serviceId=urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XBMCState1&Variable=IdleTime&Value=%s' % (ip, dev, music_title))
        music_title1 = music_title
```

The thing is that some time it send the command but with no value (music_title) at the end of the url and it crash the code. how could i send the url only if there something in it. I try to search on the net but without any success
Thanks
Mike

Comment: Why not just test the value of `music_title` before making the call and formatting the URL based on that test?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if music_title != music_title1:
```

to:

```
if music_title.strip() and music_title != music_title1:
```

Comment: Sounds good as long a `tag.getTitle()` never returns something comprised of nothing but spaces (which will be converted to underlines by the next statement.

Comment: If it's all spaces, it won't pass the `music_title.strip()` test, since `strip` will convert it to an empty string.

Comment: The `music_title = music_title.replace(' ', '_')` _before_ the test will change a string of all spaces to one of all underscores, so it **will** pass the `music_title.strip()` part of the conditional.

Comment: You're right, I missed that part. It's up to the OP to decide what's the correct behavior then.